# How to format text (bold, italics) in a Gmail email sent via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I've just started using Google Apps script. I'm using it to send emails from a Google Apps spreadsheet. In the email I would like some parts made bold and/or italicised but I can't find out how to do it.

PS: This is how I'm concatenating strings should it be of interest:

```
var message = "Hi " + fname + ",\n\nJust letting you know that we have your job targeted for " + targetDate+ ".\n\nPlease let w know if that is unsuitable.\n\nThanks, Gregg";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the html body option, see doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29), a [search on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Dhtml%2bmail) will return a lot of practical examples...